# Find if an array can form a graph

Tags: java, graph, vertices

[Interview Question] I got this question in a recent online interview. I had no clue how to solve it. Can anyone please help me solve this so that I can learn in Java.

Tom is very good in problem-solving. So to test Tom's skills, Jerry asks Tom a graph problem. Jerry gives Tom, an array A of N integers.

A graph is a simple graph, iff it has no self-loop or multi-edges.

Now Jerry asks Tom whether he can design a simple graph of N vertices or not. The condition is that Tom has to use each and every element of A exactly once for the degrees of vertices of the graph.

Now, Tom wants your help to design his graph. Print "YES" if the graph can be designed, otherwise print "NO" (without quotes).

Input 
A single integer T, in the first line, denoting the number of test cases.
For each test case, there are 2 lines.
The first line is a single integer N, denoting the number of elements of array A.
The second line has N-space separated integers, representing elements of A.

Output 
For each test case, print "YES" or "NO" (without quotes) whether the graph can be designed or not, in a new line.

Constraints

```
1<= T <= 100 
1<= N <= 100 
0<= Element of A <= 5000
```

Sample Test Cases

Input

```
1
2
1 1
```

Output

```
YES
```

Explanation
For this test case, a simple graph with 2 vertices can be designed, where each vertex has degree 1.

Input

```
2
3
1 2 1
3
1 1 1
```

Output

```
YES
NO
```

Explanation
For the first test case, we can design a simple graph of 3 vertices, which has degree sequence as [1, 2, 1]. The first vertex has degree 1, second, has 2 and third has 1.
For the second test case, we cannot make a simple graph of 3 vertices, which has degree sequence as [1, 1, 1].

Comment: your explanation is confusing and problem does not seem to be well defined. you are saying that third line is the elements separated by space and then later interpret the third line as the degree of vertices. The test case line is unnessary and has nothing to do with the problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One necessery condition is that sum of elements in A is even. That is due each edge
is counted twice in adjencency list.

Next is to try to construct graph, or at least 'allocate' pairs of nodes.

```
Sort elements of A in decending order,
Let the largest (first) element be a,
Check are element on positions 2 to a+1 larger than 0,
  If there is a element with value 0 than it is not possible to construct a graph,
Decrease these a elements by 1 and set first element to 0,
Repeat process until all elements are 0.
```

Note that sorting in subsequent steps can be done in O(n) with merge sort step, since list consists
of three sorted parts:

- first element (0) which can go to the end,
- sorted part with a elements,
- rest which is also sorted.